# Replace not working as expected with commas, inverted commas and

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe train and it has characters like commas, inverted commas etc. So i have tried to replace them as below,

```
train['content']=train['content'].replace('…','')
train['content']=train['content'].replace('”','')
train['content']=train['content'].replace('“','')
train['content']=train['content'].replace('’','')
```

However even after replacing them, I am still getting the characters as it. There is no change in content. The `commas`, `inverted commas` and `...` still exist.

There are 30,000 rows in my train dataframe. I wish to replace above mentioned characters from all 30,000 rows

**EDIT :**
train

```
content
[sure, tune, …, watch, donald, trump, “,”, late, ’ , night]
[abc, xyz, “,”,late, ’, night]
```

Basically content column is a list

Comment: try this, ```data['content'].str.replace("...|`|’|“", '', regex=True)```

Comment: Will this work if my column has list in each row as shown?

Comment: With this also , there is no change, tried on my data. Inverted commas, ... still exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using regex. It'll solve your problem

```
import re
train['content'] = train['content'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))
```

Try it for all the columns of Dataframe:

```
train = train.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: pls tell if column has list elements

Comment: Send me sample what you want.

Comment: check after edit

Comment: Your code is giving this error....TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: wait a second...

Comment: train = train.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True)

Comment: This works, but there is no space between words. They are togther so I am getting [suretunedonaldtrump] as output. spaces are all gone.... if i do `train = train.replace(r'\W+', ' ', regex=True)`  notice space between inverted commas, still there is no space between words

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into a list, them use a list comprehension:

```
train['content'] = [i for a in ['…','”','“','’'] for i in train['content'].tolist() if a not in i]
```

UPDATE:

```
train['content'] = [i if a not in i else None for a in ['…','”','“','’'] for i in train['content'].tolist()]
```

Or:

```
train['content'] = pd.Series([i for a in ['…','”','“','’'] for i in train['content'].tolist() if a not in i])
```

Comment: pls try your answer on this dataset above. It is not working....The ..., inverted commas etc still exist

Comment: I don't see your dataset.

Comment: each row is a list in train dataset column content. First row is `[sure, tune, …, watch, donald, trump, “,”, late, ’ , night]`, second row of dataset is `[abc, xyz, “,”,late, ’, night]`....this dataset is mentioned in my question, please refresh your screen if not visible since i added it after an edit

Comment: hey im getting error : ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Did my update help?

Answer (score 0):

To work with text data in dataframes, you often need to apply additional accesser "str".
In this case your commands shall look like:

```
train['content']=train['content'].str.replace('…','')
train['content']=train['content'].str.replace('”','')
train['content']=train['content'].str.replace('“','')
train['content']=train['content'].str.replace('’','')
```

Below you have small example that it works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt':['dfghn,.4567','.,.,fw,.,r4.34,']})
q = df.txt.str.replace('.','')
q
Out[150]: 
0     dfghn,4567
1    ,,fw,,r434,
Name: txt, dtype: object
```

Comment: pls tell for list as shown above